# Get list of entities whose fk related entity does not contain id in list of ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

I have two tables - Products and SKUs, related one to many.

I have a third table, rental, which contains sku ids that have been rented.

Products have a number of related SKUs - so product 1 may have sku 1, 2, and 3 for instance.

Customers rent products by SKU. So SKU 1 may be out of inventory, but there are still 2 SKUs left in inventory, meaning the product is still available.

If all 3 SKUs are rented (are in the rental table), the product is unavailable.

I need to query the context for Products that have SKUs remaining in inventory.

I'm trying to do this by getting a list of products, a list of unavailable SKUs, and returning those products whose SKUs are not in the unavailable SKU list.

I have an iQueryable of products...

```
IQueryable<products> p = (from r in db.products from pc in r.productcategories 
where pc.categories.categoryname == n select r)
.OrderByDescending(s => s.productname).Take(18);
```

and a list of unavailable skus...

```
List<int> rentedskus = new List<int>();
rental = rental.Where(t => sd < t.enddate && t.startdate < ed);

foreach (var r in rental)
{
    rentedskus.Add(r.skuid);
}
```

Things get sloppy here, but I get a list of product skus from my product list...

```
List<products> plist = p.ToList();
List<int> productskus = new List<int>();
foreach(var pr in plist)
{
    foreach(var sk in pr.sku)
    {
        productskus.Add(sk.skuid);
    }
}
```

Now, assuming this is an acceptable way to achieve my goal, I need to select only those products whose related SKUs are not in rentedskus. I've tried a few variations of...

```
var productlistresult = productskus.Except(rentedskus).ToList();
p = p.Where(i => i.productlistresult.Contains(product.skus(n => n.skuid));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were pretty much there with your last sample code, you just have some logic errors. This is what you need:

```
p = p.Where(i => productlistresult.Contains(i.skuid));
```

Also, you can clean up your code considerably, by using `Select`. For example, instead of creating a list, querying the rented skus, then iterating over the skus and adding them to the list, just do:

```
var rentedskus = rental.Where(t => sd < t.enddate && t.startdate < ed).Select(t => t.skuid);
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. The product table does not have a skuid. I can only get the skuid through the sku table...

Comment: Okay, then you would just do something like `i.skus.Any(s => productlistresult.Contains(s.skuid))`.

Comment: Perfect - thanks. p = p.Where(i => i.sku.Any(s => productlistresult.Contains(s.skuid)));